# Android Textview EditText Bugs

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext, textview

I am learning Java from Stanford online to make a simple android project.
it requires to make a simple shopping list.

Requirement: when the user clicks When the user clicks on “Add Item”, whatever is currently in the EditText should be added to the bottom of your Shopping List and when the user clicks on "clear List", you should clear the contents of the TextView.

Bugs: I am having difficulty with adding items to the TextView when the user click the button.

Its hard to describe the bug so I put the picture of my project here:

[image]

The porject should look like this pic:

[image]

It would be nice if someone could tell what is my mistake and what should I do, Thanks

The following is my code:

```
package com.stanford.ca108.shoppinglist;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void add(View view){
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textoutput);
        EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        String a = edit.getText().toString();
        textView.append(a);
    }

    public void cleantext(View view){
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textoutput);
        textView.setText(" ");
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.stanford.ca108.shoppinglist.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoutput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Please List your items" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bgroup"
        android:hint=" "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bgroup"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text = "additem"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="add"
            />
        <Button
            android:text = "clear list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="cleantext"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please do at least explain what the bugs are. We won't make an Android project, copy your code there, build and run it just to see what bugs you have.

Comment: It's hard to figure out looking at the code shared. Can you share what exceptions are you getting? Are they compiler errors or runtime exceptions? Have you added the activity to the manifest and all that?

Answer (score 1):

```
//XML layout in the propertise of the Additem button

 android:onClick="additem"

// in Java Class


//set an onclick event listener for the Additem Button


public void additem(View view) {

    String itme1 = editview1.getText.toString;
    String itme2 = editview2.getText.toString;
    String itme3 = editview3.getText.toString;

    String TotalItem = item1+"\n"+item2+"\n"+item3;

    ShoplistTextView.setText(TotalItem);

    // this would trigger the method that would set all edittext to be //empty is the cart has been filled after 
    //pressing the additem button

    checkifShoplistIsNotEmpty();

}

public void checkifShoplistIsNotEmpty(){
    String check =cartTextView.getText.toString;
    if (!check.isEmpty()){
        editview1.setText("");
        editview2.setText("");
        editview3.setText("");
    }
```